# How to activate Salesforce org when it is automatically deactivated?

Tags: licenses, deactivate

When I am attempting to login to my Salesforce account (both Production & Sandbox), it is saying

"Your company's salesforce.com account has been deactivated. You can easily reactivate your service by subscribing to salesforce.com now. Please email us at info@jp.salesforce.com or call (03) 4222-1000. Thank you."

I emailed to the email address, but NO reply yet. I called to that number, noone accept the call.

I am facing this problem from yesterday. I/my user did nothing e.g. unnecessary workflow or anything that can block the access. One possible situation is I was running Employee Cloud license, but forgot to pay the FEE within the trial month, but I believe, Salesforce is supposed to email me rather than directly deactivate which I can't even access now. Any suggestion how to solve this issue. 
I am very much afraid now if all my development get lost (like LinkedIn) as my Salesforce org is deactivated. :(

[image: Login Problem]

Comment: Does your company have a Sales/Account Relationship Manager assigned. I belive he may be able to help you out.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, don't panic. Salesforce holds on to orgs for a grace period, so all of your data, configuration, and users you set up during the trial are all still there. You should have approximately 30 days to get a hold of somebody before this data would be deleted. As long as you can still see that error, they haven't deleted your org. Second, the sales team usually responds to inquiries the same business day for emails, and are usually available over the phone during normal business hours.

Alternatively, during your trial, an Account Executive should have sent an email to the administrator for your org. Check your email, and it should include an email address and phone number you contact to get your service back up and running. Finally, you can go to [Salesforce (English)](https://www.salesforce.com/) or [Salesforce (Japanese)](https://www.salesforce.com/jp/) and click on the link in the upper right corner ("Contact Us" or 「導入前のお問合せ」). Again, you should normally get a response within a business day.

Comment: What I can do right now to accelerate the process!

Comment: @tanmoy You can likely get back up and running within the next 12 hours, just try using the Contact Us links above if you can't get anyone on the phone.

Comment: No luck yet. Not sure what to do